# Android MapFragments Manually

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to get google maps v2 working by manually initialising it rather than setting it up in the xml file. I'm trying to follow the sample app but when I run my app all I get is the map without any location. I think it may have something to do with the fragment tag as I'm not sure what thats doing. Here is the code to set up the fragment from the demo app:

```
private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "map";
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // It isn't possible to set a fragment's id programmatically so we set a tag instead and
        // search for it using that.
        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        // We only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            // To programmatically add the map, we first create a SupportMapFragment.
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

            // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        // We can't be guaranteed that the map is available because Google Play services might
        // not be available.
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

setUpMapIfNeeded
{
    if (mMap == null) {
                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you call setUpMapIfNeeded in onStart or onResume?

Comment: Ahh thats what I was missing. Thanks!